# Is there a dataset for the Federal congressional voting record?

Tags: data.gov

The data.gov initiative has a large variety of digital data sources for every agency of the government, but Congress has ZERO data sources for their own voting records.

If someone can find it please let me know.

Answer (score 4):

[GovTrack](https://www.govtrack.us/) has [congressional voting records data](https://www.govtrack.us/congress/votes). Including in bulk, JSON files https://www.govtrack.us/developers/data